# Make container accessible only from localhost

Tags: docker, portforwarding

I have Docker engine installed on Debian Jessie and I am running there container with nginx in it. My "run" command looks like this:

```
docker run -p 1234:80 -d -v /var/www/:/usr/share/nginx/html nginx:1.9
```

It works fine, problem is that now content of this container is accessible via `http://{server_ip}:1234`. I want to run multiple containers (domains) on this server so I want to setup reverse proxies for them.

How can I make sure that container will be only accessible via reverse proxy and not directly from `IP:port`? Eg.:

```
http://{server_ip}:1234  # not found, connection refused, etc...
http://localhost:1234  # works fine
```

**//EDIT:** Just to be clear - I am not asking how to setup reverse proxy, but how to run Docker container to be accessible only from localhost.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Specify the required host IP in the [port mapping](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/#/connect-using-network-port-mapping)

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:1234:80 -d -v /var/www/:/usr/share/nginx/html nginx:1.9
```

If you are doing a reverse proxy, you might want to put them all on a user defined network along with your reverse proxy, then everything is in a container and accessible on their internal network.

```
docker network create net
docker run -d --net=web -v /var/www/:/usr/share/nginx/html nginx:1.9
docker run -d -p 80:80 --net=web haproxy
```

Comment: See also https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy to do auto-reverse-proxies.

Comment: This gives me an error of `invalid publish opts format (should be name=value but got '127.0.01:3010:3010').`

Comment: FML it's just an invalid IP - `127.0.01` instead of `127.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 14):

Well, solution is pretty simple, you just have to specify `127.0.0.1` when mapping port:

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:1234:80 -d -v /var/www/:/usr/share/nginx/html nginx:1.9
```