# Docker node.js app not listening on port

Tags: node.js, express, docker, port

I'm working on a node.js web application and use `localhost:8080` to test it by sending requests from Postman. Whenever I run the application (npm start) without using Docker, the app works fine and listens on port `8080`.

When I run the app using Docker, The app seems to be running correctly (it displays that it is running and listening on port `8080`), however it is unreachable using Postman (I get the error: `Could not get any response`). Do you know what the reason for this could be?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8  
WORKDIR /opt/service
COPY package.json .
COPY package-lock.json .
RUN npm i
COPY . .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

I build and run the application in Docker using:

```
docker build -t my-app . 
docker run my-app
```

I have tried binding the port as described below, but I also wasn't able to reach the server on port `8181`.

```
docker run -p 8181:8080 my-app
```

In my application, the server listens in the following way (using `Express`):

```
app.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log('listening on port 8080');
})
```

I have also tried using:

```
app.listen(8080, '0.0.0.0', () => {
    console.log('listening on port 8080');
})
```

The docker port command returns:

```
8080/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:8181
```

Do you guys have nay idea what the reason for this could be?

**UPDATE**: Using the IP I obtained from the docker-machine (`192.168.99.100:8181`) I was able to reach the app. However, I want to be able to reach it from `localhost:8181`.

Comment: Are you using the right IP address for the docker machine?

Comment: @Spidy I am not sure how can I check?

Comment: Are there any errors in the container?  Run your server with `docker run -name my-container -p 8181:8080 my-app` and then run `docker logs my-container`.

Comment: @zero298 Nope, no errors. When I run it it logs: `listening on port 8080`

Comment: Use `docker exec -it my-container bash` to create a shell instance in the container, then use Curl to verify that something is listening on the guest port 8080.

Comment: It's my understanding that you don't access containers with your localhost, you access them via the docker machine's ip. You can get the ip with: docker-machine ip dev
https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/ip/

Comment: @Spidy No, I have a mongo server that lives in my docker and I access it through localhost:HOST_PORT which is mapped to the internal mongo port.  I mean, unless the docker machine isn't actually hosted on the OPs machine.

Comment: @zero298 I used curl: 
`curl localhost:8181` and got the response: `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8181: Connection refused`

Comment: @Spidy I will try it out now, however I would prefer to reach my server using localhost

Comment: And you did that within the docker container?  Then your app isn't actually running or has stopped failed to bind to that port.  In that same container shell check that your process is still running with `ps -A`.

Comment: @Spidy it worked, I was able to connect to my app using the IP I obtained from my docker-machine `192.168.99.100:8181`

Comment: @zero298 the app is running, I was able to reach it using `192.168.99.100:8181` in postman. Do you know what the reason could be for it not being reachable from `localhost:8181`

Comment: Is docker installed on your machine (localhost) or another machine?  Sorry, `192.168.0.1` isn't actually localhost, `127.0.0.1` is.

Comment: @zero298 as far as I know I installed the docker on my machine. I followed this doc to do so: https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way you have your port assignment setup requires you to use the docker machine's ip address, not your localhost. You can find your docker machines ip using:

```
docker-machine ip dev
```

If you want to map the container ip to your localhost ports you should specify the localhost ip before the port like [this](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/ip/):

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:8181:8080 my-app
```

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39404280/make-container-accessible-only-from-localhost):